# Add rowspan to first td of each row using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ecmascript-6, html-table

I have a table. I want to add rowspan to the first td of each row. But when I do that, it is messing up the table and pushing my data in the table to right.

This is my code:

```js
let data = [
  {device: 'iphone',   site: 'google', val1:10, val2:20, val3:30},
  {device: 'iphone',  site: 'bing', val1:23, val2:12, val3:14},
  {device: 'iphone',  site: 'jeeves', val1:67, val2:78, val3:12},
  {device: 'ipad',  site: 'google', val1:10, val2:20, val3:30},
  {device: 'ipad',  site: 'bing', val1:23, val2:12, val3:14},
  {device: 'ipad',  site: 'jeeves', val1:67, val2:78, val3:12},
  {device: 'mac',   site: 'google', val1:10, val2:20, val3:30},
  {device: 'mac',   site: 'bing', val1:23, val2:12, val3:14},
  {device: 'mac',   site: 'jeeves', val1:67, val2:78, val3:15}  
]

let heads = Object.keys(data[0]);
heads.forEach(d => $(`#headers`).append(`<th>${d}</th>`));

data.forEach(td => {
  $(`#body_deets`).append(`<tr></tr>`);
  heads.forEach(th => {
    $(`#body_deets > tr:last`).append(`<td>${td[th]}</td>`);
  });
});

$(`#body_deets > tr > td:first-child`).each(function() {
    $(this).attr('rowspan', '3');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class='table' border=1>
  <thead><tr id='headers'></tr></thead>
    <tbody id='body_deets'></tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see, this is adding the rowspan and pushing a lot of my data to the right.

How can I get my table to look like this:

[image: table with rowspan]

Is there a way to do this using jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to combine every three cells into a single cell, you need to set the `rowspan` on the first of the three cells, then remove the next two:

```js
let data = [{
    device: 'iphone',
    site: 'google',
    val1: 10,
    val2: 20,
    val3: 30
  },
  {
    device: 'iphone',
    site: 'bing',
    val1: 23,
    val2: 12,
    val3: 14
  },
  {
    device: 'iphone',
    site: 'jeeves',
    val1: 67,
    val2: 78,
    val3: 12
  },
  {
    device: 'ipad',
    site: 'google',
    val1: 10,
    val2: 20,
    val3: 30
  },
  {
    device: 'ipad',
    site: 'bing',
    val1: 23,
    val2: 12,
    val3: 14
  },
  {
    device: 'ipad',
    site: 'jeeves',
    val1: 67,
    val2: 78,
    val3: 12
  },
  {
    device: 'mac',
    site: 'google',
    val1: 10,
    val2: 20,
    val3: 30
  },
  {
    device: 'mac',
    site: 'bing',
    val1: 23,
    val2: 12,
    val3: 14
  },
  {
    device: 'mac',
    site: 'jeeves',
    val1: 67,
    val2: 78,
    val3: 15
  }
]

let heads = Object.keys(data[0]);
heads.forEach(d => $(`#headers`).append(`<th>${d}</th>`));

data.forEach(td => {
  $(`#body_deets`).append(`<tr></tr>`);
  heads.forEach(th => {
    $(`#body_deets > tr:last`).append(`<td>${td[th]}</td>`);
  });
});

$(`#body_deets > tr > td:first-child`).each(function(index) {
  if(index % 3 == 0) {
    $(this).attr('rowspan','3');
  } else {
    $(this).remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class='table' border=1>
  <thead>
    <tr id='headers'></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id='body_deets'></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

For the colspan elements, you need only 1 `<td>`. Just remove the extras like this:

```
$(`#body_deets > tr > td:first-child`).each(function(index,elem) {
        if (index%3!=0) $(this).remove();
         else $(this).attr('rowspan', '3');
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I would calculate the index ranges ahead of time. See the `indexRange` function and the `rowSpan` assignment.

```json
{
  "iphone": { "first": 0 , "last": 2 },
  "ipad":   { "first": 3 , "last": 5 },
  "mac":    { "first": 6 , "last": 8 }
}
```

```js
const data = [
  { device: 'iphone' , site: 'google' , val1: 10 , val2: 20, val3: 30 },
  { device: 'iphone' , site: 'bing'   , val1: 23 , val2: 12, val3: 14 },
  { device: 'iphone' , site: 'jeeves' , val1: 67 , val2: 78, val3: 12 },
  { device: 'ipad'   , site: 'google' , val1: 10 , val2: 20, val3: 30 },
  { device: 'ipad'   , site: 'bing'   , val1: 23 , val2: 12, val3: 14 },
  { device: 'ipad'   , site: 'jeeves' , val1: 67 , val2: 78, val3: 12 },
  { device: 'mac'    , site: 'google' , val1: 10 , val2: 20, val3: 30 },
  { device: 'mac'    , site: 'bing'   , val1: 23 , val2: 12, val3: 14 },
  { device: 'mac'    , site: 'jeeves' , val1: 67 , val2: 78, val3: 15 }  
 ]; 

let fields =  Object.keys(data[0]);
fields.forEach(d => $(`#headers`).append(`<th>${d}</th>`));

const indexRange = data.reduce((acc, { device }, index) =>
  ({ ...acc, [device]: {
    first: acc[device]?.first ?? index,
    last: index || acc[device]?.last
  } }), {});

console.log(indexRange);

data.forEach((record, rowIndex) => {
  $(`#body_deets`).append(`<tr></tr>`);
  const { device } = record;
  const { first, last } = indexRange[device];
  fields.forEach((field, colIndex) => {
    const value = record[field];
    if (colIndex === 0) {
      if (rowIndex === first) {
        const rowSpan = last - first + 1;
        $(`#body_deets > tr:last`).append(`<td rowspan="${rowSpan}">${value}</td>`);
      } 
    } else {
      $(`#body_deets > tr:last`).append(`<td>${value}</td>`);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, th, td {
  border: thin solid #CCC;
}

th, td {
  padding: 0.33em;
}

thead > tr {
  background: #DDD;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #EEE;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr id="headers"></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="body_deets"></tbody>
</table>
```